# Stitching together an array of tiles

Tags: c#, xna

Suppose I have an array of Rectangles corresponding with tiles in a texture atlas.  What I want to do is take these tiles and create a Texture2D object out of them.  Basically, I want to put the pixel data of each tile together sequentially to form one image.  How could I go about doing this?  Would `Texture2D.SetData()` be of use here?

Comment: You could draw it all to a `RenderTarget2D` and then reuse it as a `Texture2D`, but there might be a better way to do what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Would a shader based approach be an option for you? I mean transforming the texture coordinates in the pixel shader, so that they always wrap into the specified rectangle.

Comment: I went with the RenderTarget2D option.  Have to test it out still though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RenderTarget2D target = new RenderTarger2D(...); 
//I cant remeber the arguments off the top of my head.
//I think its GraphicsDevice, Width, Height, GenerateMipmap, SurfaceFormat, Depthformat

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(target);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black); //any colour will do
using(SpriteBatch b = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice))
{
   b.Begin();

   //Loop through all texture and draw them, so ...
   for(int y = 0; y < 10; i++)
     for(int y = 0; y < 10; i++)
       batch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height), Color.White));

   b.End();
}

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

//Then to access your new Texture, just do 
Texture newTexture = target; //Target inherits from Texture2D so no casting needed
```

Hope this helps :)